# Definition of chaos: R.May's science paper (1974)

Tags: recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems

I am interested in the following standard dynamical system:
$N_{t+1}=N_t exp[r(1-N_t/K)]$.

In R.May's 1974 science paper (pp.645, Table1, Biological populations with non overlapping generations),he states that chaotic behaviour (cycles of arbitrary period, or aperiodic behaviour, depending on initial condition.) occurs if r>2.692.

However in the same paper (pp.646), he also says that if r>3.102, then it can be shown that the dynamical system above has cycles of period 3.

I do not see any point of stating the second result since May has already shown that this dynamical system generates a cycle of period 3 (or cycles of any period) if r>2.692.

Anybody has any thought?

Comment: The first statement gives the "chaotic" region where both aperiodicity and arbitrary periodicity occur. The second statement gives a particular subset of the chaotic region where period-$3$ occurs. ([link here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/18754203_Biological_Populations_with_Nonoverlapping_Generations_Stable_Points_Stable_Cycles_and_Chaos))

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, things are still not clear for me. First statement already implies that the dynamical system above has cycles of period 3 if r>2.692 since it has cycles of any period if r>2.692.

Also, by the Li-Yorke theorem, period 3 implies chaos, so it looks like May is stating two different sufficient conditions (r>2.692 and r>3.102) to generate chaos. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: _Period three implies chaos_ was published in 1975.